# Windows/Linux vs Mac 2019

Tags: windows, osx, hardware

You are always recommended to use windows/Linux to run blender but all the forum questions seem to be outdated by 7 years. I only thought of this because people tend to prefer to use photoshop and other graphics or filmmaking apps on mac. Is there an actual answer or is it just preference? Thanks.

--Edit--

***Research***

https://www.reddit.com/r/photography/comments/76ssig/why_do_so_many_photographers_seem_to_use_mac_over/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHnHanyERug

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpE2B2QSsa0 - Mac OS is similar to linux

Comment: "*I only thought of this because **people tend to prefer** to use photoshop and other graphics or filmmaking apps on Mac.*" **[Citation Needed]** As a living counterexample, I would like to see some of your research (the advantages of any of the systems regarding Blender).

Comment: This is more of a statement than a question.  Please read [ask] and [tour] and rephrase this as an answerable question. As @Leander has requested, citing resources for your research is essential otherwise this is a purely subjective claim.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect @Leander comment

Comment: I'd advise against using macOS if your graphics card is made by AMD, since OpenCL has been deprecated. Therefore Cycles doesn't support GPU rendering on macOS in Blender 2.80. Blender doesn't use Metal or MoltenVK yet,

Answer (score -1):

People tend to work on Mac in the film and graphic industry because Mac towers are very modular, and the interface is easy to use and more reliable. But all tech guys I've seen, including 3D artists, worked on Linux or Windows, because it's just better for this kind of stuff. I think some GPU stuff are missing on Mac in Blender 2.8. Linux being the best if you like to get your hand dirty and can do a bit of coding, but only IF you don't work with Photoshop and can get away with Gimp. I personally stayed on Windows for this reason. At the end of the day choose whatever environment you like, this won't affect Blender all that much. But if you don't know, just go for Windows.

Comment: Downvoted. This seems more like opinion than researched facts.

Comment: Is it? I mean compared to how the question was asked?